# android.graphics.Paint hardness

Tags: android, paint

I'm doing a simple drawing app, and so far I've managed to control the opacity and size of the brush.
Now I'm  trying to set some kind of hardness, like in Photoshop, but I looked at the documentation and Paint doesn't seem to have something like that.
In case it's relevant, I'm following [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-essential-functionality/)

tutorial.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
//brush sizes
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize; 
//erase flag
private boolean erase=false;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

//setup drawing
private void setupDrawing(){
    //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

//size assigned to view
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

//register user touches as drawing action
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;

}

//update color
public void setColor(String newColor){
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}

//set brush size
public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    brushSize=pixelAmount;
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
}

//get and set last brush size
public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
    lastBrushSize=lastSize;
}
public float getLastBrushSize(){
    return lastBrushSize;
}

public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    erase=isErase;
    if(erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
}

//start new drawing
public void startNew(){
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

So, how can I set a Paint's hardness?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
private Paint drawPaint= new Paint();
drawPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

Where the first parameter of BlurMaskFilter is the radius of the blur :)

Comment: Please explain this. It is not working in my case. no effect at all.